# Python 2.7: Reading a text file online to a string and printing output

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading data from this link: http://www.weerindelft.nl/clientraw.txt.

The main goal is to print out the temperature http://www.weerindelft.nl displays. I have discovered that its in that text file so i only need to print out the right part of the file.

This is my code:

```
import socket
from decimal import Decimal

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                 
s.connect(("www.weerindelft.nl" , 80))
s.sendall("GET http://www.weerindelft.nl/clientraw.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n")
write = s.recv(1427247693)
variable_1 = str(write[311:])
integer = float(variable_1[46:50])
tim = round(integer,0)
print Decimal(tim)
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(write)
f.close
s.close()
```

This is my output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 04 Jan 2017 12:34:14 GMT

Server: Apache

Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Jan 2017 12:34:12 GMT

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Content-Type: text/plain

X-Varnish: 110069959 109349321

Age: 32

Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)

ETag: W/"b173bdaf-2fb-54544008156e2"

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Content-Length: 763

Connection: close

12345 7.0 7.8 318 5.4 85 1016.9 1.0 4.2 4.2 0.014 0.086 18.7 38 100.0 34 0.0 0 0 0.2 -100.0 255.0 -100.0 -100.0 -100.0 -100.0 -100 -100 -100 13 20 58 WeerinDelft-13:20:58 2 100 4 1 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 2.6 4.0 8.0 5.1 34 zonnig/Gestopt_met_regenen 0.2 4 4 4 7 5 5 8 6 6 5 6 6 4 4 4 4 5 6 9 8 30.4 3.0 949.9 4/1/2017 7.5 3.6 6.0 0.9 0.5 14 12 10 12 7 11 8 5 6 10 6.8 6.9 6.7 6.5 6.4 6.5 5.7 5.3 5.1 5.3 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.8 1.0 1.0 1.0 8.0 5.1 5.4 18.2 0 13:09:41 2017/04/01 326 522 91 -100.0 -100.0 5 0 0 0 0 102.0 18.9 18.7 4.7 1017.2 1014.5 24 12:40 10:35 6.1 0.8 6.2 1.5 15 2017 -13.9 -1 1 -1 341 336 336 309 331 358 336 318 310 318 10.0 255.0 7.5 4.4 51.97944 -4.34139 0.6 90 66 1.0 10:46 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 249.8 05:47 13:11 !!C10.37S13!!
```

I have used requests before and it worked like a charm. Unfortunately the assignment is to use the socket module. I think i know where the problem lies but not to solve it. I need to get rid of the HTTP code and information and just be able to read the file so i can print out the right part of it. Because at this very moment running this script only succeeds a couple of times because the text file is shifting and my script is focussing on:

```
integer = float(variable_1[46:50])
```

This part of the text file/string.

I hope you guys understand what I mean. My apologies in advance if this post has some flaws. Its my first one and I am fairly new to programming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Response seprates the header and content with a blank line. 
So you can use

```
write.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)[1]
```

to get rid of the HTTP code and information, extract only the content of the response.